# Using Migrations with Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm just trying to use migrations in my .Net Core class library, but for some reason I have the following return:

```
$ dotnet ef migrations add InitialMigration
No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef"
```

I googled many times, but none of examples are applicable to my scenario.

My solution looks like this:

[image]
And my context class:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using VirtualStore.Data.Mapping;

namespace VirtualStore.Data
{
    public class Context<T> : DbContext where T : Entity
    {
        public DbSet<T> Entity { get; set; }

        public Context()
        {
            Database.EnsureCreated();
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source=DESKTOP-3UEM3PC;Initial Catalog=VIRTUALSTORE;Integrated Security=SSPI;");
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        }
    }
}
```

And my repository class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using VirtualStore.Data.Mapping;
using VirtualStore.Models.Data.Repository;

namespace VirtualStore.Data
{
    public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : Entity
    {
        public Context<T> Context { get; set; }

        public void Delete(T entity)
        {
            using (Context = new Context<T>())
            {
                Context.Remove(entity);
                Context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        public void DeleteAll(IEnumerable<T> entities)
        {
            using (Context = new Context<T>())
            {
                Context.RemoveRange(entities);
                Context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<T> Get(Func<T, bool> predicate)
        {
            using (Context = new Context<T>())
            {
                return Context.Entity.Where(predicate).ToList();
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
        {
            using (Context = new Context<T>())
            {
                var all = Context.Entity.OrderBy(x => x.Id).ToList();
                return all;
            }
        }

        public T GetById(long id)
        {
            using (Context = new Context<T>())
            {
                return Context.Entity.Where(x => x.Id == id).OrderBy(x => x.Id).FirstOrDefault();
            }
        }

        public void InsertAll(IEnumerable<T> entities)
        {
            using (Context = new Context<T>())
            {
                Context.Entity.AddRange(entities);
                Context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        public void Insert(T entity)
        {
            using (Context = new Context<T>())
            {
                Context.Entity.Add(entity);
                Context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        public void Update(T entity)
        {
            using (Context = new Context<T>())
            {
                Context.Update(entity);
                Context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        public void UpdateAll(IEnumerable<T> entities)
        {
            using (Context = new Context<T>())
            {
                Context.UpdateRange(entities);
                Context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Project link: https://github.com/otaviolarrosa/VirtualStore

Can anyone help me? What is wrong with my command to start using migrations?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the following to the *VirtualStore.Data.csproj* file in your *VirtualStore.Data* project.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.1" />
</ItemGroup>
```

After saving the change, you should be able to access those commands from a command prompt. The command prompt current directory will need to be in the same directory as the *VirtualStore.Data* project.

Without this reference, those commands are not available.